# WPF Trigger and VisualState at the same time?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I use a `Trigger` `IsSelected` and a `VisualState` `MouseOver` at the same time? I wan't to apply a style if an element is not selected and it is hovered.

Triggers alone are easy:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        ...
                    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

and so are VisualStates alone:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                ...
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

But how do I combine these?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `VisualState x:Name="Selected"` in a new `VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedStates"`. Then, because at a time controls have only one state from each group, MouseOver and Selected are independant from each other. See [Mitesh Sureja's Blog](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.de/2011/05/visual-state-manager-new-feature-in.html).

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                ...
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                ...
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Or you could do as Clemens suggested. See [Visual State Manager vs. Triggers in WPF](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.de/2011/05/visual-state-manager-vs-triggers-in-wpf.html).

**Edit**

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter ... />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: This does not work, because I want to apply a style when *both* are occurring. The above code applies two different sets of styles depending on 4 different scenarios (Over + Selected, Over, Selected, Nothing). All I want is 2 scenarios (Over + Selected, Nothing).

Comment: Then try a [MultiTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger.aspx).